# For loop to delete vertex attributes in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to delete multiple vertex attributes in igraph. So far I tried a for loop with the delete_vertex_attr function. however, for some reason it only deletes the last attribute in my list. Below is a simplified example:

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10,.3)

g <- set_vertex_attr(g,"a", index = V(g), 1)
g <- set_vertex_attr(g,"b", index = V(g), 1)
g <- set_vertex_attr(g,"c", index = V(g), 1)
g

l<- c("a", "b", "c")
for (i in l){
  g2<-delete_vertex_attr(g, i)
}
g2
```

I am new to R and coding in general and would help very much appreciate. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement `g2<-delete_vertex_attr(g, i)` is always going back to the original g to delete one attribute.  You need to keep deleting from the new graph g2.

```
g2 = g
for (i in l){
  g2<-delete_vertex_attr(g2, i)
}
g2
```

Comment: This also seems to work: `g2 = g; vertex_attr(g2)[l] <- NULL` ... not sure if it's the right way to go though.